# Fastest way to unlock all the characters in Smash Bros Ultimate?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

I want to have the full character roster as quickly as possible.  What is the fastest way to accomplish this?

Comment: @Wondercricket I have to remember to search for the dupe before answering...

Comment: I looked but i missed it somehow.  And your answer did give information that the other question doesnt have so it was still useful =)

Comment: One is to do a classic battle, then quit game and relaunch... rinse and repeat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On any type of battle, the distance your character travels is stored. Each X meters (I don't know the actual amount) you have the chance to get an encounter and fight a new character. Usually, after each battle you should wait for a 10 minutes cool-down, which can be bypassed just closing the game after the new character is beaten and unlocked.

The procedure is simple:

- start a Stock match with no time, just kill yourself jumping off the platform, no matter who wins
- you should get another encounter
- beat the character, and go back to the menu
- close the game
- rinse and repeat

You should get an encounter each time, because the timer resets restarting the game.

(**Farming the distance**: If you haven't traveled enough, you can farm your traveled distance setting up a Stock battle of 20 minutes against a second player, no CPU, no items, no hazards or whatever. Choose a straight plain level, and just run for 19:30 minutes and then knock the other player off to win the battle.)

In this way, unlocking each character should take you no more than 90 minutes of play. Unless you have some stored traveled distance you got playing yourself of with friends, in that way you should be able to immediately exploit the random encounter method without running for 20 minutes.

All credits goes to *Austin John Plays*:

<sub>(April 2022, the method still works, according to the comments)</sub>